# How do I setup a swagger-typescript generator as part of our build process?

Tags: typescript, webpack, swagger, yarnpkg

We use yarn and webpack to build our frontend Angular application. I think we follow a pretty standard structure with AOT compilation for development and standard prod deployment via Jenkins. The directory structure is basically:

```
./
package.json
webpack-aot.config.js
webpack.config.js
src
    |
    app
    assets
```

Our backend microservices use maven to identify swagger files, use a code generator to create HTTP bindings to those services, and create model files to represent the requests and responses those services deal with. The swagger code is generated at build time and placed in a separate directory that is included as part of the compilation so we don't need to include it in our code base.

**I want to do something similar with our frontend project**. Is it possible to:

1. Use a utility like `swagger-typescript-codegen` or some other utility to generate a swagger integration?
2. Have that code generation occur when running yarn to build our application?
3. Skip this step on a developer's machine if the code has already been generated and everything is current?
4. Generate this code into a separate folder/directory that can be included into a .gitignore so that it is not part of our codebase (we would only commit the swagger)?

I think number #1 is obviously a "yes". But I am not sure what is possible in questions 2-4 nor what best practices are. I also have not discovered a lot of information about this on the web so I am wondering if this is considered a bad approach for front-end development.